# Matching/Correlating lists of email addresses

Tags: php, email, laravel-4

We have a monthly mass email send where we receive lists of email addresses from various clients, which will *mainly* be the same month on month.

I'm trying to find a way of matching the lists to each client using their previous month's list so I don't need to specify which list is for which client - in short a way of correlating a new list of email addresses to a previous one even if some are new or have dropped out, or if the order is different.

Is there a function or statistical test I can use for this? I could just do a manual count through each row of the new list to see if mainly it has the same email addresses in it as an old one, but that would be resource heavy.

Platform is Laravel 4.2. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a routine that iterates through list 'A', comparing each address with line #1 of list 'B'. To cut down on resources, have the routine return a true or false value after 10 iterations of list 'A', incrementing the line number in list 'B' each time list 'A' is iterated.

Comment: That's the way we are going to do it, I was wondering if there was some sort of statistical method but an in-memory list comparison is the way to go. Thanks.